# Pages wont work in blogger template

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have downloaded this template:

http://btemplates.com/2009/blogger-template-mobipress/

The xml code is too long to post here.

The problem I am having now, is that pages when I put content, its not appearing.
Example here:
http://idaytradeforaliving.blogspot.be/p/routines.html

I am not sure what other information can I put here to help with the problem

I found this

```
   <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>

<div expr:id='&quot;summary&quot; + data:post.id'><p><data:post.body/></p></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>createSummaryAndThumb(&quot;summary<data:post.id/>&quot;);</script>



                    <div class='clear'/>




<div class='singleinfo'>

        <div class='more'> <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'><b:if 

cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
                            <a expr:href='data:post.url'>Full Story</a>
                        </b:if></b:if></div>
</div>

</b:if> </b:if>
```

Comment: What was on that page befor you use new template ? I see that other pages look good.

Comment: it might be because of the template, have you re-changed your template to see where the problem really is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your blog posts are all displaying correctly. That narrows down the problem. If ALL your static pages show no content, then there is a condition on all static pages which is causing the problem.

To find the CSS conditions placed on all static pages (assuming all the pages are not displaying content):

1. Login to your Blogger.com account
2. Go to your Template page on Blogger.com
3. Click the gray button named "Edit HTML"
4. Search and find (if you're using a windows system- hold "Ctrl" and press "f"):

   ```
   <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
   ```

If you found the correct one, you should see something similar to this (except with CSS codes in the middle):

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<style>
CSS codes here
</style>
</b:if>
```

The CSS codes is where your problem will likely be. Something in one of those codes is stopping all the static pages from displaying content. If you know CSS + HTML you can likely spot it. If not, copy and paste the CSS codes (by editing your Stack Overflow question) and I will look into it for you.

### Edit: Part 2:

The part of the template that I was refering to would have been above the `/b:skin` (if style related) or `/head` (if script related, not style related). Also you would have seen CSS codes between the conditions, not HTML codes.

However, I downloaded the template and uploaded it to test the pages. The pages are also not working on my end.

Usually problems like this are style or script related. However, the source of this problem is that whoever created this template gave a condition to not show post summaries on static pages but post summaries is the only way to show the content. What they failed to do was make a new condition for static pages, hence nothing showed up on static pages.

The code you pasted in your question, this is how it should look:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'> 
<div expr:id='data:post.id'><p><data:post.body/></p></div>
       </b:if>

     <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'> 
     <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>

<div expr:id='&quot;summary&quot; + data:post.id'><p><data:post.body/></p></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>createSummaryAndThumb(&quot;summary<data:post.id/>&quot;);</script>
       </b:if>

                <div class='clear'/>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>

<div class='singleinfo'>

    <div class='more'><b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
                        <a expr:href='data:post.url'>Full Story</a>
                    </b:if></div>
</div>
</b:if>
</b:if>
```

That should fix your problem. Happy blogging! :)

### EDIT (Blogger: Comments not showing on blog posts):

First, to narrow down the problem and get the simple fixes out of the way:

> 1.The problem could be that the comments are turned off on your settings page. To check:

1) Click on the "Settings" tab.

2) Under the "settings" tab, once clicked, a new menu will appear under that section. Click on the one named "Posts and comments".

3) In that page, you will have information about "Posts" and under that section is for "Comments". Make sure where it reads "Comment Location" that the drop-down menu is selected on "Embedded". If not, click that and then click the orange button "Save Settings" (in the upper-right hand corner).

> 2: Blogger is designed is such a way that if you are looking at the posts from the homepage and you have post summaries enabled (which with your template, you do) then you can't see the comments until you click "Full Story".

If you want the comments to appear on the homepage also, you have remove post summaries from the template. This changes based on what template is being used.

> 3.Make sure the comments is checked on the Layout page:

1) Click on the "Layout" tabs.

2) Click on the "Edit" button in the lower-right hand corner of the square box called "Blog Posts".

3) Under the "Post Page Options" make sure the "Comments" box has a checkmark next to it. If it doesn't, click that box and then click the orange "Save" button on the very bottom.

> 4.Changing the template on the "Template" page where you click "Edit HTML" could cause other problems or glitches. Did you change your template at all, besides the changes I know about? When I loaded the template as a test site on blogger (even after the changes from your first question), the comments appear on my end, so the problem you're experiencing is not related to the fresh upload of the template.

Also check this:

> 5.Inside each post, even if comments are turned on, you have a choice to make all comments hidden for that certain post. Check and make sure that the correct option is selected.

1) Open the blog post in question, by going to the "Posts" tab.

2) Find the post you want comments to be shown on and click the title.

3) In the sidebar, right-hand side, you have a list of "Post Settings". Click the 
"Options" menu.

4) Make sure under "Reader comments" the selected option is "Allow" and **not "Don't allow, show existing " or "Don't allow, hide existing**".

These are the over-looked and simple solutions to making comments appear in the blog posts. Check the list above and if everything is correct and the problem still remains, let me know and I will look into it further.

Comment: I added the static part of the template, but not sure what to do to fix it.

Comment: thanks a lot, that fixed the problem, now I am having another problem, comments to posts are not visible, if you want I can post another question for that and link it here?

Comment: Sure, just post the link here.

Comment: here its http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643598/bloggger-template-is-not-showing-comments

Comment: would you help me here? I had to delete the question.

Comment: thanks a lot for your information, the problem was even simpler, I turned on the use Google+ comments, the comments are there but on a google+ thread.  thanks a lot for your time\